# Find the server tomcat started or not?

Tags: java, tomcat

In my desktop application, I am connecting to a server through a web service.
Using the code below getting the client machine Tomcat status, I can get the server IP address and port number, but how can I find the server Tomcat status?

```
InetAddress locIP = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080, 0, locIP);
```

Comment: Can you use [JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html)?

Comment: This code doesn't get any such thing as a 'client machine Tomcat status', whatever that is. It will fail if Tomcat is already running on this host, assuming it uses a Connector on port 8080, or indeed if anything is already listening on port 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java's `URLConnection` as follows:

```
       try {
                URL url = new URL("http://youserver.com");
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2000); //Connection timeout
                urlConnection.connect();
                System.out.println("Server is up and running");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Server is not yet up");
            }
```

if `urlConnection.connect()`returns silently within 2 seconds, means the server is up and running, else an exception is thrown which indicates the server is not up or the URL is incorrect.

Comment: You should also call `dispose()` in the success case.

Comment: @EJP I could not find `dispose()` method in `URLConnection`. Which object you are referring ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant [`HttpURLConnection.disconnect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()).

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do to detect a running Tomcat here or elsewhere is to try to connect to it with a `new Socket().` If that works, it's running; if not, not. Don't send anything, just close the socket immediately.